# iOS Safari Screen.orientation.lock() is not working

Tags: ios, safari, locking, screen, orientation

With iOS 16.4, Safari supports locking the screen orientation according to the MDN compatibility table, but I can't get it to work.

I can return the screen.orientation.type property, but as soon as I try to lock it like this:

screen.orientation.lock("portrait-primary");

Nothing seems to happen.
I don't get any errors, and the returning promise doesn't throw any errors either.
Also screen. addEventListener("onorientationchange") doesn't get registered somehow.

I am testing my PWA standalone on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following information concerning the iOS 16.4 updates:

> Added support for ScreenOrientation.type, ScreenOrientation.angle, and
> ScreenOrientation.onchange.

So I guess the lock() method is still not supported.
Concerning the eventListener I found a solution:

```
screen.orientation.addEventListener("change", ...);
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-16_4-release-notes